# global variables, arrays, and search results

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, interface-builder, global-variables

I am trying to write an app that searches a website, and takes all of the results and puts them into a customized table. I am an Objective-C and iPhone SDK noob, and am hoping that this logic is what I am trying to accomplish:

1) Searching multiple search engines and pulling all of the data off of each website, storing each into a different array (for example: Searching Google, Yahoo, and Bing for "Shoes", and taking all of the different search results, hyperlinks and all, and storing them into three different arrays)

2) Pulling the data out of each array, and putting into a table (Table view in Interface Builder)

I am assuming that I need to declare global variables, so that they can be called from different classes......right?
What's the syntax for doing this?
How do I set this up in IB?
Did I bite off more than I can chew for this first app?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are biting off a little much in my opinion. Read the documentation and play with the sample applications on the Apple website. Try a small task first such a displaying a table view with some static content, maybe just a few strings. Then take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am doing just that, but it is hard for me to take big tasks and break them off into smaller pieces. I feel that when I learn to do that properly, my little programming skills will soon grow!

Answer (score 1):

Aaron, I also think you're biting off more than you can chew WRT a single question on SO, but let me point you to a [resource I wrote](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/10/15/how-to-consume-json-or-xml-web-apis-on-iphone-smoothly/) on a similar topic about how to structure your program.

As an Obj-C noob, you're going to need to take extra care to remember the Model-View-Controller pattern.  Extracting data from a web site is a bit of work - and you want to keep that very separate from your display and control code.

Have a clean API model that extracts and sorts data, and have a clear view controller class that reads data from the API.

My advice is to write the whole app in psuedo-code first and try out your thinking on us.

Comment: I have pseudo-code. Can I send it to you, and you can let me know where my thinking needs adjustment? That would be fantastic!

Comment: Aaron - sorry for the delay in response.  You can reach me via my profile -- I'll be happy to help.